# Using PHP to transfer a txt file from one server to another

Tags: php, curl, ftp, transfer

Thank you.

Here is the cURL ftp code I have tried to use most recently, together with the response I am getting.

$str contains ascii text (a php script).

```
I have no problems at all accessing
ftp://hostingdomain/auth/
and the files within it, on a read or write basis, with an FTP client
(in the case OSX Fetch) in either passive or active mode.
In essence, I am trying to create (write) test.php within
ftp://hostingdomain/auth/
, and overwrite it if it is already there. The tmp file is being correctly created,
and deleted once the script exits.

$ch = curl_init();
$tmp = tmpfile();
fwrite($tmp, $str);
fseek($tmp, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://hostingdomain/auth/test.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myftpusername:myftppassword");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $tmp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($str));

curl_exec ($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
fclose($tmp);

if ($error_no == 0) {
$message = 'File uploaded successfully.';
} else {
$message = '<BR>File upload error: '.$error_no.' '.$error.'<BR>';
print_r ($info);
}
echo $message;
```

--------Response - Script is being run on "sending" server.

```
Array ( 
[url] => ftp://hostingdomain/auth/test.php
[content_type] =>
[http_code] => 227
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 16.64937
[namelookup_time] => 0.200538
[connect_time] => 0.288836
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => 0
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0 
)
File upload error: 7 
couldn't connect to host
```

Essentially I am getting a timeout and then the above $info and $message 
comes back. Doing exactly the same transfer into
`ftp://hostingdomain/auth/test.php` with my FTP client works just fine.

Comment: It's impossible to help you without knowing specifically what you've tried (with code), and what these issues are that you don't understand.  This is not a site where we will write code for you.  This is where you come to learn.  If that's not what you want, then I suggest hiring a consultant.

Comment: Why do you think I came here? To LEARN of course - hence the question! I could post you many lines of code that I've tried and had issues with - mainly obscure issues that are not providing me with helpful error output. This must be a common need, hence my request not for you to WRITE code (which I did not ask for!), but to share anything useful. Anyway, plenty of other helpful people out there who I'm sure can help me....rather put off by what I've got back here so far!

Comment: You shouldn't be put-off... I'm trying to explain to you what's wrong with the question, as it has been posted.  cURL and FTP are exactly the solutions you should be using for this.  It is a common need.  If you can't explain what the problem was with those, there is nothing we can do for you.

Comment: Thank you.

Here is the cURL ftp code I have tried to use most recently, together with the response I am getting.

$str contains ascii text (a php script).

I have no problems at all accessing ftp://mydomain/auth/ and the files within it, on a read or write basis, with an FTP client (in the case OSX Fetch) in either passive or active mode.
In essence, I am trying to create (write) test.php within ftp://mydomain/auth/, and overwrite it if it is already there. The tmp file is being correctly created, and deleted once the script exits.

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
$tmp = tmpfile();
fwrite($tmp, $str);
fseek($tmp, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://mydomain/auth/test.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myftpusername:myftppassword");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $tmp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($str));
curl_exec ($ch);

Comment: $error_no = curl_errno($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
fclose($tmp);
if ($error_no == 0) {
$message = 'File uploaded successfully.';
} else {
$message = '<BR>File upload error: '.$error_no.' '.$error.'<BR>';
print_r ($info);
}
echo $message;

Comment: --------Response - Script is being run on "sending" server.

Array ( [url] => ftp://mydomain/auth/test.php [content_type] => [http_code] => 227 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 16.64937 [namelookup_time] => 0.200538 [connect_time] => 0.288836 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 0 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 )
File upload error: 7 
couldn't connect to host

Comment: -Essentially I am getting a timeout and then the above $info and $message comes back. Doing exactly the same transfer into ftp://mydomain/auth/test.php with my FTP client works just fine.

Comment: Youv'e tried this script on your machine where FTP is working?  Many hosts won't allow outbound connections like this.

Comment: Yes, the server running the script does support outbound and inbound ftp connections.....